# Python executable failing to use SQLAlchemy with error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'" when called through SQL

Tags: python, sql, executable

I have a python script that I've converted to an executable using PyInstaller. The executable itself works fine when run directly or through powershell, but when I attempt to call it in T-SQL (using SSMS) I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'" on the part in the script that attempts to fetch data from the database using SQLAlchemy. I'm running the executable using `exec xp_cmdshell` and it seems to find and start the program without issue, only failing at a specifc part in the code.

Any idea why this is happening? The executable was created in a virtual enviroment with all necessary packages installed, inclduing Pyodbc (though it's not directly used, but I take it SQL Alchemy uses it). If exec xp_cmdshell simple starts the executable through a command line command, I don't see how it can work normally but fail in SQL.

Comment: I think PyInstaller only takes direct module imports into account. Do you have any indirect pyodbc module imports in your scripts? If so you can try the `--hidden-import pyodbc` option.